# type hyperlink not found in xmlns http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms

Tags: listview, hyperlink, xamarin.forms, label, navigateuri

I am trying to make an app, and I wanted to have text with hyperlink, but whenever I try to run my app it gives me this error: "Error       Position 68:40. Type Hyperlink not found in xmlns http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms FamilyEvents    C:\desenv\Family\FamilyEvents\DetailsPage.xaml  68  "

My code is this:

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dy7lt.jpg)

Comment: please include the code, not an image

Answer (score 0):

`<Hyperlink />` is not a Xamarin Forms control.

You can achieve something similar by using a `Label` control with a `TapGestureRecognizer`.

Answer (score 0):

The type you are using `Hyperlink` is not a control within Xamarin.Forms, so it gives you an error that it is not a type which is found in the default namespace.

If you want such functionality use a `Label` control on which you can tap with a `TapGestureRecognizer`. The code could look like this:

```
<Label Text="My link">
    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

And in your code behind implement the `OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped` event which opens your link.